# Deformation retraction definition – why need the requirement $f_t|A = \mathrm{Id}$ for all $t$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, definition, retraction

There's a part of the definition of deformation retraction that I keep forgetting, and that is because I cannot understand why it is required.

The definition states (from Hatcher's *Algebraic Toplogy*):

> A deformation retraction of a space $X$ onto a subspace $A$ is a family of maps $f_t \colon X \to X$, $t \in I$, such that $f_0 = \mathrm{Id}$, $f_1(X) = A$, and $f_t|A = \mathrm{Id}$ for all $t$. The family $f_t$ should be continuous.

Why do we need the requirement $f_t|A = \mathrm{Id}$ for all $t$? Where might things break if this is not required? Is it because we want $A$'s homology to not be potentially modified along the way? If there's an example where this matters that would be great (I played around with $D^2$ but couldn't really identify a potential issue beyond the homology intuition I just mentioned).

Comment: You got the right idea, you don't want break the algebraic structure on $A$. You'll be looking at the injection $A \rightarrow X$ and the groups attached to it later and this simplifies things.

Comment: Here is my intuition for this: in many cases (for example in the proof of Whitehead’s theorem), we use the relative homotopy groups $\pi_n(X,A)$ to construct a desired homotopy equivalence. And in the CW universe, one can consider one cell at a time to construct such a map. You choose a cell, use the relative homotopy group (which is trivial) to deformation retract that cell to $A$. The point is, many homotopy equivalences arise as deformation retracts. You can consider this relative homotopy idea as an example to what @CyclotomicField called “groups attached” to injection.